# Qualtrics: How do I overlay piped text onto an image/graphic?

Tags: javascript, image, qualtrics

On Qualtrics, I am trying to overlay/superimpose text from previously filled-out answers onto an image.

I know how to pipe text (e.g., ${q://QID181/ChoiceTextEntryValue/1}) into a future question, but I am unsure of whether there is code I can manually input in Qualtrics to superimpose this piped text over an image.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance for any and all help!